# When to keep application data in memory?

Tags: android, angularjs

This might be a very noob question and I am new to android framework.
I have read about ngrx redux and flux design pattern in angular where the whole application state is kept in a js object. I wonder why we do not keep application state in a single object in android apps ?? Is this because mobile devices have lesser RAM ?

Comment: It will depend  on your application. If you want to keep app state you can use ViewModel kind of approch

Comment: Yes the view model will serve this purpose but it lasts as long as activity. But in angular we keep state and data as long as the application is active. My basic doubt is is there is very strong reason why the state is not kept as long as application life.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is because of performance benefits for the end-user. If application state is hold in-memory there are no network latencies etc. which significantely improves the response times and finally gives the user a much more pleasent interaction with your application.

Comment: Agreed thats why I wanted to implement it. I guess The View Model approach will somehow serve this purpose.